# Python Crawler: deal with "load more" button

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am learning python crawler and I want to know how to deal with the "load more" button located in the following url:

https://www.photo.net/search/#//Sort-View-Count/All-Categories/All-Time/Page-1

(I was trying to crawl all the picture)

Current code I have is using beautifulsoup:

```
from urllib.request import *

from http.cookiejar import CookieJar

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.photo.net/search/#//Sort-View-Count/All-Categories/All- Time/Page-1'

cj = CookieJar()

opener = build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

try:
    p = opener.open(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(p, 'html.parser')

except Exception as e:

    print(str(e))
```

Comment: Have you tried to increment the page number at the end of the URL?  You can try to loop through some number of pages and scrape what is there.

Comment: Yeah, I tried, but it cannot be loaded unless you click that button.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have a solution for you.

You should try Selenium module for python.

1) Download Chrome Driver

2) Install Selenium via pip

Here is an example of how to use it

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome('Path to chrome driver')
browser.get()
while True:
    button = WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Load More')))
    button.click()
```